# Relationship between two time-series

Tags: r, time-series, arima

I am trying to analyse the impact unemployment levels has on a party’s vote share. 
My data-set is composed of two timeseries, both with monthly observations from 1989 – 2017.
I tested both for stationarity and made unemployment stationary when I saw it wasn’t. 
I have read that ARIMA is good for achieving what I want, i.e. see how much changes in unemployment may have led to changes in vote share, but I cannot for the life of me get it to work in R.

I used auto.arima on the two time-series independently, and then forecast on them and that works

```
test1 <- auto.arima(ts(Votetimeseries))

fcast <- forecast(test1, h=30)
```

However, im not interested in forecasting, but rather how they impact each other.

My online searching led me to using xreg with auto.arima

```
xreg     <- c(as.factor(statUtime))

modArima <- auto.arima(ts(Votetimeseries), xreg=xreg)
```

But this only produces this error:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = x ~ xregg, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'xregg')

In addition: Warning message:`
In !is.na(x) & !is.na(rowSums(xregg)) :
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

I'm completely new to Time-series analysis, having only some experience with regression etc, so I hope someone can help or show me what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: The message says that the objects aren't of the same length so, are they? If they are, make sure you've properly set the frequency/start/end on your `ts` objects so they can be aligned properly. Also, do you really have unemployment rate as a `factor`? Why?